# Phpunit not running correctly on windows subsystem for linux

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpunit, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've install phpunit on to my windows subsystem for linux:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-7.1.1.phar
chmod +x phpunit-7.1.1.phar
sudo mv phpunit-7.1.1.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

I can see that phpunit exists in `/usr/local/bin/phpunit`

When I run `php phpunit --version` from `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` it runs correctly.

However from anywhere else I get the following error:

```
 Could not open input file: phpunit
```

I also see this error when I run just `phpunit --version`

```
-bash: /usr/bin/phpunit: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have no idea what I did but it suddenly started working.

Comment: The shell keeps a cache where to find which executable. see `hash`; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

Answer (score -1):

```
php /usr/local/bin/phpunit --version
```

This form works..., actually I have php and phpunit installed via apt and they install into /usr/bin... so I actually used

```
$ php /usr/bin/phpunit --version
```

PHPUnit 5.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.